# why my format doesn't work in boost log

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I am using `boost::log` in this function:

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>

void InitLog() {
  logging::core::get()->set_filter(logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::debug);
  logging::add_file_log(
            keywords::file_name = AppHolder::Instance().config().log_folder + "/sign_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.%N.log",
            keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
            keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
            keywords::format = "%TimeStamp% (%LineID%) <%Severity%>: %Message%"
            );
}
```

Then, given the call:

```
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "thread id: " << this_thread::get_id() << " Initialization succeeded";
```

Output is not as expected: *timestamp*, *line id* and *severity* are empty.

> () <>: thread id: 7f58e30e8740 Initialization succeeded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding this, the problem was solved.

> boost::log::register_simple_formatter_factory<
>   boost::log::trivial::severity_level, char >("Severity");

Full code is located at my blog
[use boost log step 4](http://csfreebird.blogspot.com/2013/12/use-boost-log-step-4.html)

Comment: One thing to notice in the linked blog post: it looks like you need to call `register_simple_formatter_factory` _before_ the call to `add_file_log`. (Arguably obvious, but I messed it up anyway.)

Answer (score 17):

You have to register these attributes with the log core. Like this:

```
boost::log::add_common_attributes();
```

Or manually:

```
boost::log::core::get()->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", boost::log::attributes::local_clock());
// etc...
```